# Should I put Romex in ENT above a drop ceiling?

Tags: electrical, wiring

We purchased a portable commercial building and we are converting it to a residential building.  All the wiring is run in smurf tube.  We are adding wiring for a kitchen and laundry room that require 6 3 romex for stove, dryer and on demand water heater.  It will be installed above a drop ceiling which is allowed by code since it is single family residence.  Should we put the romex in 1 inch ent tube or staple it to the bottom of the roof rafters?

Comment: You have ENT, so you don't need NM/B at all. Just use ENT and THHN wires.

Comment: _Can_ you put it there (as asked in the title question) or _should_ you put it there (as asked in the question body)? Those are different questions and might get you different answers. Please feel free to [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Using THHN wires in conduit now can make life much easier in the future if they need changing, just disconnect and pull.  Romex/NM-B can be used in conduit, but it is very low on the list of best ideas, harder to pull is one.  The conduit might need to be bigger for cable size than separate wires.

Comment: NEC 312.5 has confusing restrictions about running cable in conduit, into a cabinet that are difficult to satisfy, I think it restricts to entering the top, limits length of conduit and requires securing cable to cabinet, it's all kind of confusing. Even if you cross all the T's and dot the I's what you gain is questionable.

Comment: And btw it looks like 6/3 can be as small as 0.62" diameter, at 53% fill for cable as a single conductor would require  1" ENT.